# Play WAV at certain time?

Tags: c#, audio, timer, wav

Very new to C#, and I'm finding I have an odd code problem. I have the Express version of C# 2010. I need a WAV file to play at certain times, such as 10AM, 1130AM and 2PM, as examples. I can get the WAV to play using a button, but not at any certain time without clicking the button. Any ideas or suggestions? I've been trying to use the Timer event, but when that is used, not even the button will work.

Comment: Can you show us the code that is not working, maybe then with some help of us you'll get to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a timer. Lets set **Interval** of the timer to 1 second. Then on timer tick event **check the current system time**. If it matches with the specific time(11 AM / 11:30 AM / 2PM) then stop the timer and play the sound. Once the playing of the sound is over then start the timer again.

```
private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DateTime todayNow = DateTime.Now;

        // For 11 AM
        if (todayNow.Equals(new DateTime(todayNow.Year, todayNow.Month, todayNow.Day, 11, 00, 0)))
        {
            MyTimer.Stop(); // Stop the timer before you play the wav file
            PlaySound();
        }
        // For 11 30 AM
        else if (todayNow.Equals(new DateTime(todayNow.Year, todayNow.Month, todayNow.Day, 11, 30, 0)))
        {
            MyTimer.Stop(); // Stop the timer before you play the wav file
            PlaySound();
        }
        // For 2 PM
        else if (todayNow.Equals(new DateTime(todayNow.Year, todayNow.Month, todayNow.Day, 14, 00, 0)))
        {
            MyTimer.Stop(); // Stop the timer before you play the wav file
            PlaySound();
        }
}


// Once the Sound playing is over you can start the timer immediately
void OnSoundPlayOver
{
   MyTimer.Start(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to one I made that is similar to what you are asking. In it the user sets how many seconds (ticks) they want to count down, and when it finishes counting, it plays "YellowSubmarine". So, this isn't time-based, but hopefully it will get you on the right track:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;

namespace TickCounter_MGilliland
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        int NumberOfTicks;
        SoundPlayer Song = new SoundPlayer("YellowSubCut.wav");
        bool AlarmGo = false;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            NumberOfTicks = 1;

            SecondTimer.Interval = 1000;
            SecondTimer.Enabled = true;

            Progress.Maximum = 100;
            Progress.Value = 0;
        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (InputTicks.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Get the number of ticks that the user wants and set the input to ""
                    NumberOfTicks = Int16.Parse(InputTicks.Text);
                    InputTicks.Text = string.Empty;
                }
                catch (Exception s)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Exception: "+ s.ToString());
                    InputTicks.Text += " <-FixMe";
                }

                if (NumberOfTicks > 0)
                {
                    // Set ShowTicks' text to the number of ticks and show it
                    ShowTicks.Text = NumberOfTicks.ToString();
                    ShowTicks.Show();

                    InputTicks.ReadOnly = true;

                    AlarmGo = true;
                    Progress.Value = Progress.Maximum = NumberOfTicks;

                    // Start the timer
                    SecondTimer.Start();
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Input Must be an unsigned number greater than 0!");

            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("I can't count ticks you haven't given, Sherlock!");
        }

        private void StopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InputTicks.ReadOnly = false;
            SecondTimer.Stop();
            ShowTicks.Text = string.Empty;
            ShowTicks.Hide();
            Progress.Value = 0;
            Song.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Phew... I'm glad you stopped that...\nIt was really starting to tick me off.");
        }

        private void SecondTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (NumberOfTicks > 0)
            {
                // Decrease the number of ticks and change the value in ShowTicks
                ShowTicks.Text = (--NumberOfTicks).ToString();
                Progress.Value = NumberOfTicks;
            }
            else
            {
                NumberOfTicks = 0;
                SecondTimer.Stop();
                if (AlarmGo)
                    Song.PlayLooping();
                AlarmGo = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. It's working like a dream now. I appreciate the assistance!